# Reduce javascript code for jQuery CSS changes (open/close off-canvas navigation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on creating a custom off-canvas navigation similar to how Foundation works. Basically I have 2 icons with `click` triggers to adjust the CSS. I was wondering if it would be possible to reduce code by making this into a single toggle function instead of 2 separate functions with 2 separate divs for opening/closing. Here is what I am currently working with:

```
jQuery(".navMenuOpen").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".page-wrapper").css("left", "70%");
    jQuery(".off-canvas-nav").css("left", "0")
    jQuery(".navMenuOpen").css("display", "none");
    jQuery(".navMenuClose").css("display", "block");
});
jQuery(".navMenuClose").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".page-wrapper").css("left", "0");
    jQuery(".off-canvas-nav").css("left", "-100%")
    jQuery(".navMenuOpen").css("display", "block");
    jQuery(".navMenuClose").css("display", "none");
});
```

Is it possible to reduce this to a single function/HTML element?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not add appropriate css and toggle a class on a common parent element? I.e. `.click( function () { $('body').toggleClass ('showMenu'); } )`. Much less code.

Comment: Thanks @AD7six, I am reading up on toggleClass right now, looks like this will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something in these lines.

```
jQuery(".navMenuOpen, .navMenuClose").click(function (event) {
    var wrapperLeft = '70%',
        canvasLeft = '0',
        openDisplay = 'none',
        closeDisplay = 'block',
        $this = $(this);

    event.preventDefault();

    if($this.hasClass('navMenuClose')) {
        wrapperLeft = '0',
        canvasLeft = '-100%',
        openDisplay = 'block',
        closeDisplay = 'none';
    }
    jQuery(".page-wrapper").css("left", wrapperLeft);
    jQuery(".off-canvas-nav").css("left", canvasLeft)
    jQuery(".navMenuOpen").css("display", openDisplay);
    jQuery(".navMenuClose").css("display", closeDisplay);
});
```